# How to show $P[X\geq k] \leq (\frac{\lambda e}{k})^k e^{-\lambda}$ (X is Poisson random variable)

Tags: probability, inequality

Let $X$ be a Poisson random variable with $\lambda > 0$

Show

$\mathbb{P}[X\geq k] \leq (\frac{\lambda e}{k})^k e^{-\lambda}\qquad, \forall k \geq \lambda$

I'm having quite some trouble to show this.

So far I have

$\mathbb{P}[X \geq k] = 1-e^{-\lambda} \sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\frac{\lambda^{i}}{i!}$
$=1-e^{-\lambda}\left( e^{\lambda}- \sum_{i=k}^{\infty} \frac{\lambda^{i}}{i!}  \right)= e^{-\lambda} \sum_{i=k}^{\infty} \frac{\lambda^{i}}{i!}$

I could then make a rather crude estimation that shows $\sum_{i=k}^{\infty} \frac{\lambda^{i}}{i!} \leq e^k$ but I don't think that is right.

Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** $$\sum_{i=k}^{\infty} \frac{\lambda^i}{i!} = \left(\frac{\lambda}{k} \right)^k \sum_{i=k}^{\infty} \frac{k^k \lambda^{i-k}}{i!} \stackrel{k \geq \lambda}{\leq} \left(\frac{\lambda}{k} \right)^k  \sum_{i=k}^{\infty} \frac{k^i}{i!}$$

Comment: Big-ass hint! Thanks so much. I did not see that.

Answer (score 0):

Another way by Chernoff bounds:

For any $\rho\geq0$ we have $$\mathsf P(X\geq k)=\mathsf P\left(e^{\rho X}\geq e^{\rho k}\right)\overset{\text{Markov's ineq}}\le e^{-\rho k}\,\mathsf E\left(e^{\rho X}\right)=\exp\big(\lambda(\exp(\rho)-1)-\rho k\big),$$

where I have used the well-known representation of the moment generating function of the poisson distribution.

Setting $\rho=\ln\left(\frac k\lambda\right)\geq0$ leads to $$\mathsf P(X\geq k)\le\exp\left(k-\lambda- k\ln\left(\frac k\lambda \right)\right)=e^{-\lambda} \left(\frac{\lambda e}k\right)^k.$$